# Website returns 502 once put behind a load balancer

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have this website that works but once it is placed behind a load balancer, it gives a 502 error. After some troubleshooting, this snippet is the culprit.

```
    if( function_exists( 'is_shop' ) && is_shop( ) ){
        // $redirect_page_id = 132; // adjust to ID of page you are redirecting to */
        wp_redirect( '/product-category/main-dish/' , 301 ); exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'shop_redirect' );
```

I want the shop page, which is also the home page, to be a specific product archive page. Hence, I do a redirection. The above snippet works fine but once I added a load balancer, it fails to work. It returns a 502 error. I don't understand why it stops working behind a load balancer.

The error from load balancer is `statusDetails: "failed_to_pick_backend"`

What I am trying to is to have the product archive page to be the home page. The approach I attempted is to have the home page `domain.com` to redirect to `domain.com/product-category/main-dish/`

I've tried many different ways to configure the load balancer and lost track of them. This is the current setting and I've tried with enabling and disabling the code snippet.

**Just a recap:**

1. The website works correctly with the redirection snippet enabled.
2. However, once it is placed behind a load balancer, it produces 502 error
3. With a load balancer, there is no 502 error when the redirection snippet is disabled
4. When the redirection snippet is enabled, it produces 502.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that code is the problem? You have tagged **google-cloud-load-balancer**. Show the configuration of the load balancer and health check. Show the output from Cloud Logging for 502 errors.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley Thanks. Once it is placed behind the load balancer, when the code is disabled, it works. When the code is enabled, it returns a 502 error. Hence, I find that the snippet meant for redirection is the problem.

Comment: Review the logs to find the actual error. Did you review the logs? If yes, post them in your question. Otherwise, your question does not contain the details required to help you debug your problem and might be closed.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley Just added to the OP. the error is `statusDetails: "failed_to_pick_backend"`

Comment: The error **failed_to_pick_backend** means that the load balancer could not select a healthy backend. Your health checks are failing. Is your code in the health check path?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Do you mean if the path for health check is set to `/product-category/wallet/` as in my case?

Comment: What is the health check endpoint? Go back to my first comment asking for details.

Comment: @JohnHanley Have them up there

Answer (score 0):

Check the health check you created while creating load balancer , add health check firewall rule if health check is showing unhealthy status even though instance is working fine.

Comment: Thanks. I reckon the loadbalancer healthcheck is fine. It works when i disabled the snippet for redirection. It produces 502 when the redirection snippet is enabled.

Comment: Did you use any hardcoded ip address in code when you are redirecting from this code snippet?

Comment: Thanks. No hardcoding of IP or domain